# IE below 11, jquery Easydropdown doesn't select last item in Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

To initialize drop down, I used

```
    var $selects = $('select');
    $selects.easyDropDown();
```

Which initializes dropdown.

Please check [**This**](http://www.html.it/wp-content/uploads/script/demo/b/44474/demo.html) link I referred

**Try to select** month or year (Dropdown having Scroll bar), select last item in dropdown in IE , it doesn't select.

Now the dropdown is working properly on all browsers but on any IE version(I tested 9 , 10 ) , last Element is not getting selected.

Please check dropdowns where scrolling is present,(First open the site in IE). When I select last item it doesn't select. But all items except last one are selecting.

What could be the issue?

I mean their plugin is not working in IE. What should be done to rectify?

**Please check** **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsqbt3xx/3/)** I made, you can do scrolling thru mouse pointer and still last element is not selecting.

Comment: It seems ok on IE 11

Comment: @huanfeng Okay , so does it give issue in below IE11 ?

Comment: It seems i still can select 1990 as last year on IE10 & IE9, (not real IE10 and IE9, user agent for IE10 and IE9, and i got some error message:Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .dropdown.)

Comment: on chrome it will also has the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue myself just commented this class in easydropdown.css which gave me issues in IE ->

```
/*
.dropdown.scrollable div::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;

    box-shadow: inset 0 -50px 30px -35px #fff;
}
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

use 'z-index'

```
jquery.easydropdown.js 
========================
open: function(){
...
self.$scrollWrapper.css('z-index','0'); //IE9와 IE10에서 scrollWrapper가 ul보다 앞에 나오는 현상 방지.}
=========================

easydropdown.css
==========================
dropdown ul{
...
    z-index: 1;
}
```